# Adding one more level of list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have following working LINQ code (in .Net 4.5) that convert flattened data to domain object model and then to corresponding JSON.

**JSON**

```
{
    "testTIN": "123",
    "measurements": [{
        "measureId": "001",
        "value": {
            "IsEndToEndReported": true,
            "PerformanceMet": 5
        }
    }]
}
```

**LINQ**

```
List<FlattenedRawData> rowList_NoStrata = HelperMethodClasses.GetFlattenedRawData_NoStrata();
List<MeasurementSet__NoStrata> result_NoStrata = rowList_NoStrata.GroupBy(records => records.EffectiveTIN)
                         .Select(y => new MeasurementSet__NoStrata
                         {
                             testTIN = y.Key,
                             measurements = y.Select(i =>
                                     new Measurement_NoStrata()
                                     {
                                         measureId = i.MeasureID,
                                         value = new QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata
                                         {
                                             IsEndToEndReported = true,
                                             PerformanceMet = i.PerformanceMetCount
                                         }
                                     })
                                .ToList()
                         })
                    .ToList();

string requestJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result_NoStrata[0]);
```

Now, I need to get the results in `List<MeasurementSet__MultiStrata>` instead of `List<MeasurementSet__NoStrata>` which is similar but one more level list of objects inside QualityMeasureValue (i.e. `List<Strata>`).

```
{
    "testTIN": "123",
    "measurements": [{
        "measureId": "001",
        "value": {
            "strata": [{
                    "IsEndToEndReported": true,
                    "PerformanceMet": 5,
                    "Stratum": "Level1"
                },
                {
                    "IsEndToEndReported": true,
                    "PerformanceMet": 6,
                    "Stratum": "Level2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

How to get `List<MeasurementSet__MultiStrata>` using LINQ?  All starta elements for one MeasureId should be grouped under same value element.

**Domain Classes**

```
public class FlattenedRawData
{
    public string EffectiveTIN { get; set; }
    public string MeasureID { get; set; }
    public int PerformanceMetCount { get; set; }
    public string Stratum { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement_NoStrata
{
    public string measureId { get; set; }
    public QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata value { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement_MultiStrata
{
    public string measureId { get; set; }
    public QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata value { get; set; }
}


public class QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata
{
    public bool IsEndToEndReported { get; set; }
    public int PerformanceMet { get; set; }
}


public class QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata
{
    public List<Strata> strata = new List<Strata>();
}

public class Strata
{
    public bool IsEndToEndReported { get; set; }
    public int PerformanceMet { get; set; }
}


public class MeasurementSet__NoStrata
{
    public string testTIN { get; set; }
    public List<Measurement_NoStrata> measurements { get; set; }
}

public class MeasurementSet__MultiStrata
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string testTIN { get; set; }
    public List<Measurement_MultiStrata> measurements { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What makes this question hard to get your head around is the similar naming of everything. :o i continually have to scroll up and down to check everything

Comment: In the FlattenedRawData source  for the MultiStrata case are the PerformanceMetCount, and Stratum both lists?

Comment: @Wes There is no list in FlattenedRawData class. The class is already available in the question.

Comment: fix your  MeasurementSet__MultiStrata call is same as MeasurementSet__NoStrata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how to generate resul_MultiStrata

```
List<MeasurementSet__MultiStrata> resul_MultiStrata = 
flattenedRawData.GroupBy(groupBy1 => groupBy1.EffectiveTIN)
.Select(level1 => new MeasurementSet__MultiStrata
{
    testTIN = level1.Key,
    measurements = level1.GroupBy(groupBy2 => groupBy2.MeasureID).Select(level2 =>
    new Measurement_MultiStrata()
    {
        measureId = level2.Key,
        value = new QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata()
        {
        strata = level2.Select(level3 => new Strata
        {
            IsEndToEndReported = true,
            PerformanceMet = level3.PerformanceMetCount
        }).ToList(),
        }
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

### Output

Here the output

```
[
  {
    "category": null,
    "testTIN": "EffectiveTIN_01",
    "measurements": [
      {
        "measureId": "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_01",
        "value": {
          "strata": [
            {
              "IsEndToEndReported": true,
              "PerformanceMet": 1
            },
            {
              "IsEndToEndReported": true,
              "PerformanceMet": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "measureId": "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_02",
        "value": {
          "strata": [
            {
              "IsEndToEndReported": true,
              "PerformanceMet": 3
            },
            {
              "IsEndToEndReported": true,
              "PerformanceMet": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": null,
    "testTIN": "EffectiveTIN_02",
    "measurements": [
      {
        "measureId": "EffectiveTIN_02_MeasureID_03",
        "value": {
          "strata": [
            {
              "IsEndToEndReported": true,
              "PerformanceMet": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<FlattenedRawData> flattenedRawData = new List<FlattenedRawData>()
            {
                new FlattenedRawData()
                {
                    EffectiveTIN = "EffectiveTIN_01",
                     MeasureID ="EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_01" ,
                     PerformanceMetCount = 1 ,
                     Stratum = "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_01_Stratum_01"
                },
                new FlattenedRawData()
                {
                    EffectiveTIN = "EffectiveTIN_01",
                     MeasureID ="EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_01" ,
                     PerformanceMetCount =2 ,
                     Stratum = "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_01_Stratum_02"
                },
                 new FlattenedRawData()
                {
                    EffectiveTIN = "EffectiveTIN_01",
                     MeasureID ="EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_02" ,
                     PerformanceMetCount = 3 ,
                     Stratum = "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_02_Stratum_03"
                },
                new FlattenedRawData()
                {
                    EffectiveTIN = "EffectiveTIN_01",
                     MeasureID ="EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_02" ,
                     PerformanceMetCount =4 ,
                     Stratum = "EffectiveTIN_01_MeasureID_02_Stratum_04"
                },
                   new FlattenedRawData()
                {
                    EffectiveTIN = "EffectiveTIN_02",
                     MeasureID ="EffectiveTIN_02_MeasureID_03" ,
                     PerformanceMetCount = 5 ,
                     Stratum = "EffectiveTIN_02_MeasureID_03_Stratum_05"
                },
            };
            List<MeasurementSet__NoStrata> result_NoStrata = flattenedRawData.GroupBy(records => records.EffectiveTIN)
                    .Select(y => new MeasurementSet__NoStrata
                    {
                        testTIN = y.Key,
                        measurements = y.Select(i =>
                                new Measurement_NoStrata()
                                {
                                    measureId = i.MeasureID,
                                    value = new QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata
                                    {
                                        IsEndToEndReported = true,
                                        PerformanceMet = i.PerformanceMetCount
                                    }
                                })
                        .ToList()
                    })
            .ToList();

            string requestJson1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result_NoStrata[0]);

            File.WriteAllText("output1.json", requestJson1);

            string requestJson2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result_NoStrata);

            File.WriteAllText("output2.json", requestJson2);


            List<MeasurementSet__MultiStrata> resul_MultiStrata = flattenedRawData.GroupBy(groupBy1 => groupBy1.EffectiveTIN)
                   .Select(level1 => new MeasurementSet__MultiStrata
                   {
                       testTIN = level1.Key,
                       measurements = level1.GroupBy(groupBy2 => groupBy2.MeasureID).Select(level2 =>
                              new Measurement_MultiStrata()
                              {
                                  measureId = level2.Key,
                                  value = new QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata()
                                  {
                                      strata = level2.Select(level3 => new Strata
                                      {
                                          IsEndToEndReported = true,
                                          PerformanceMet = level3.PerformanceMetCount
                                      }).ToList(),
                                  }
                              }).ToList()
                   }).ToList();


            string requestJson3 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resul_MultiStrata[0]);

            File.WriteAllText("output3.json", requestJson3);


            string requestJson4 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resul_MultiStrata);
            File.WriteAllText("output4.json", requestJson4);



        }
    }


    public class FlattenedRawData
    {
        public string EffectiveTIN { get; set; }
        public string MeasureID { get; set; }
        public int PerformanceMetCount { get; set; }
        public string Stratum { get; set; }
    }

    public class Measurement_NoStrata
    {
        public string measureId { get; set; }
        public QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Measurement_MultiStrata
    {
        public string measureId { get; set; }
        public QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata value { get; set; }
    }


    public class QualityMeasureValue_NoStrata
    {
        public bool IsEndToEndReported { get; set; }
        public int PerformanceMet { get; set; }
    }


    public class QualityMeasureValue_MultiStrata
    {
        public List<Strata> strata = new List<Strata>();
    }

    public class Strata
    {
        public bool IsEndToEndReported { get; set; }
        public int PerformanceMet { get; set; }
    }


    public class MeasurementSet__NoStrata
    {
        public string testTIN { get; set; }
        public List<Measurement_NoStrata> measurements { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasurementSet__MultiStrata
    {
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string testTIN { get; set; }
        public List<Measurement_MultiStrata> measurements { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost. But the starta elements for same measureID is not grouped together. So it is not matching with the expected JSON in the question. One measureID is repeated multiple times. How to fix this?

Comment: @Lijo ok , just add measureID group, check it